# Getting "Years Only " from ACF Date Picker field to Hidden filed in the fields group

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a Date Picker field and text field, or hidden field, can I get the year filled up to the text field or hidden field when filling up the date picker filed?

this is for a filtring reason I do need the year only.

[image]

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for that if you want to populate that second field before hitting Publish/Draft or Update. But, if you  can, Check the [`acf/save_post`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) hook for a better solution. Can't help much as discussions on the third-party plugins are off topic.

Comment: why not just sort based on the date field itself?